# Permission to same user in multiple domains

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I have a SharePoint farm that take users from multiple domains.

Some users are present in two or more domains but on in SharePoint the second account doesn't have the same permission as the first one.

I'd like to know if there is any way to replicate the same grants to user's all accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an audience group in User Profile service with a filter to add users from both domains in that group and provide permissions to that audience group on site/library instead of users individually. For example

There is a user on two domains, Domain1\UserName and Domain2\UserName

My Target Audience = [Domain1\UserName  + Domain2\UserName]

Grant permissions to My Target Audience on SharePoint site/list directly.

Check [this](https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/chirag-mehta/2013/07/25/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-audience) link, it may help you to setup audience group.